# Load ViewController when Push Notification is received

Tags: swift

when a user receives a push notification and taps the notification, he/she will be brought into my app, where I want a certain view controller to appear. Therefore I use the notification center.

My question is, where do I need to perform the loading of the view controller so it will be shown and pushed on the navigation stack when the user enters the app?

```
func processReceivedRemoteNotification(userInfo:[NSObject:AnyObject]) {

    let notification = userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let json = JSON(notification)

    // Get information from payload
    let dispatchType:String = json["dispatch"]["dispatchType"].stringValue

    switch dispatchType {
    case "alert":
        self.notificationCenter.postNotificationName("ALERT_RECEIVED", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject:AnyObject])
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**View Controller to be loaded**

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

    let notificationCenter: NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "alertMessageReceived:", name: "ALERT_RECEIVED", object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func alertMessageReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        print(userInfo)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc1: AlertViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("example1") as! AlertViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your app architecture, but from the given context I can see that you have a `navigationController`. You should not add as observer `AlertViewController` in this case. Instead move this code to another view controller, which is already pushed to `navigationController`. Another option is to subclass `UINavigationController` and observe `"ALERT_RECEIVED"` notification in it.

Comment: the `processReceivedRemoteNotification` sits within the AppDelegate. So I would put the code to load the VC directly into the switch statement in the method above?

Comment: If you have a reference to your navigationController in AppDelegate you can do it there. Can you show me code, where navigationController is created?

Comment: OK, what is your root view controller?

Comment: my rootview is a mapview controller i load on startup which is the main view of the app

Comment: which is embedded in a nav controller

Comment: If mapview controller is always in your navigationController stack, you can observe this notification in mapview controller and push alert controller from it.

Comment: how would it work if i want to put an notification observer in the respective view controller which will listen for an incoming notif and then gets pushed on thr stack? so the app delegate sends and all VCs have a listener that triggers a func to display the Vc